# Replace keyboard interrupt (Interrupt 9) makes two calls rather than one

Tags: c, operating-system, interrupt, dosbox

Each keyboard press will enter to the function, which replaced the interrupt, twice. Why is that happing?

Maybe the "enter" after scanf is interfering? But it goes to the function twice each press and not only after first try

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it enter only once to the function for one press each time? In the pic you can see I press 5 only twice instead of 5 times

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>

volatile int ctrl_break_flag;   //counter
void interrupt(*Int9Save)(void);   


void interrupt my_func8(void)
{
  ctrl_break_flag++;
  printf("%d\n",ctrl_break_flag);
  Int9Save();
  }
void main()
{
 int N=0,i;
 Int9Save=getvect(9); //Save pointer to original interrupt.
 printf("Please enter number: ");
 scanf("%d",&N);
 setvect(9,my_func8);//Set interrupt pointer to our function.
 ctrl_break_flag=0;

 while(ctrl_break_flag<N);
   printf("End");
 setvect(9,Int9Save);//Return to original interrupt.
 return;
}
```

Comment: You get an interrupt when a key is pressed, but also when a key is released.

Comment: oh thanks, didnt knew it . so to overcome it all i can do is to make the length to be twice bigger? is there another solution?

Comment: You could check the scan code to see if it is a key-down event or a key-up event. Sorry, I don't know the details. I gave up DOS programming a couple of decades ago.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid it you can simply set integer to count the times there was an interrupt and then ignore all the odd for example.

**code example:**

```
void interrupt Keyboard(void){
    check++;
    Keyboard_Flag=1;
    if(check%2==0) //print only button pressed(will print only 
                                               odd interrupts)
    printf(" KeyPressed");
    Int9Save(); // return state
    
}
```